# Trouble importing Orfeo Toolbox into PyQGIS Console

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, orfeo-toolbox

I have Orfeo Toolbox installed and configured within QGIS 3.22.11. Unfortunately, when I attempt to import the OTB package in the PyQGIS console I get the following error: `No module named 'otbApplication'`.

I've also attempted to install OTB within a conda environment on both Windows and WSL2 but haven't had any luck either.

Can anyone assist with either issue?

Comment: Did you install OTB application separately?

Comment: Yes I have installed OTB separately. It works within QGIS, but I haven't had any luck importing the module and interacting with it within Pyqgis.